# How to compute denominator in Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, naive-bayes-classifier

Suppose we have class `C_k` and input feature vector `x` in dataset
[image]

How to calculate probability `p(x)`?

Comment: Do you need p(x)?, note that for classification with Naive Bayes one doesnt need it.

Comment: Your correct Naive Bayes doesn't need it, therefore, it's a more theoretical question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the Examples section of the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) there is a nice example.  The calculation of $p(\mathbf{x})$ can be done via

$$p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_k p(C_k) \ p(\mathbf{x} \mid C_k)$$

Note that using the [conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) assumption of the Naive Bayes one can write

$$ p(\mathbf{x} \mid C_k) = \Pi_{i} \, p(x_i \mid C_k) $$